# Comparing dates in iif() in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to use the following query in SQL Server

```
SELECT [AL].[Subscriptions].Id,
       [AL].[Subscriptions].name,
       [AL].[Subscriptions].description,
       [AL].[Subscriptions].price,
       [AL].[Subscriptions].iconFileName,
       IIf(a.expiryDate > Now(), 'TRUE', 'FALSE') AS isSubsByUser
FROM   [AL].[Subscriptions]
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT *
                  FROM   [AL].[UserSubscriptions]
                  WHERE  userId = 13259) AS a
         ON Subscriptions.Id = a.itemid;
```

but always get the error

> *Error in list of function arguments: '>' not recognized.
>   Unable to parse query text.*

How do I resolve it?

Comment: `iif` is a SQL Server 2012 function. You need `CASE` in 2008. Also `Now()` won't work either. Use `GETDATE()` or `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. So `CASE WHEN a.expiryDate > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END AS isSubsByUser`

Comment: @MartinSmith Curious - why not submit answer?

Comment: @Norla Because I voted to close as too localized instead. I can't see this question helping future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Martin Smith said you need to use a case statement.  Also it looks like you are only using a couple of fields in the derived table therefor I would suggest not using *.  I put a example below.

```
   SELECT [AL].[Subscriptions].Id,
        [AL].[Subscriptions].name,
        [AL].[Subscriptions].description,
        [AL].[Subscriptions].price,
        [AL].[Subscriptions].iconFileName,
        case when a.expiryDate > GetDate() then 'TRUE' else 'FALSE' end AS isSubsByUser
   FROM   [AL].[Subscriptions]
   LEFT JOIN (SELECT expiryDate, itemid 
              FROM   [AL].[UserSubscriptions]
              WHERE  userId = 13259) AS a
     ON Subscriptions.Id = a.itemid;
```